# Magento 2 add multiple products to cart via url

Tags: php, magento, module, magento2

I'm working on a custom module which uses the related products functionality and so all I need to do is have a button which will add all the related products on the page to the basket. I was looking at using the "data-post: action..." that comes with add to cart buttons on the related products.

Literally just needs to add all the product ID's to basket on click. Any help would be appreciate, cheers!